# Lambda is not authorized to perform: dynamodb:Query on resource - But scan works just fine

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, aws-lambda, amazon-iam

I am new to Lambda, I was playing with the lambda samples given in the AWS.

In nodeJS 6.10 Runtime,

`dynamo.query({ TableName: 'my_table', KeyConditionExpression: 'id = :id',ExpressionAttributeValues: {':id': '123'} }, done);` is erroring out with `xxxxLambda is not authorized to perform: dynamodb:Query on resource`.

But `dynamo.scan({ TableName: 'my_table'}, done);` works just fine, so does the PUT operation `dynamo.putItem(JSON.parse(event.body), done);` I haven't modified my IAM policies.

BTW, definition of `done` variable is

```
const done = (err, res) => callback(null, {
        statusCode: err ? '400' : '200',
        body: err ? err.message : JSON.stringify(res),
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        },
    });
```

## Edit

### My Lambda-IAM Original roles:

1. AWSLambdaMicroserviceExecutionRole-xxxx
2. AWSLambdaBasicExecutionRole-xxxx-xxxx-xx-xx-xx

When I attached "AmazonDynamoDBFullAccess" policy, 'query' also started to work fine. 
**But what I am wondering is how scan and put works but not query?**

## Edit-2

Dear downvoter, please add a comment so that I can improve my question.

Comment: Can you update your question with the existing IAM policy? Seems like a permission issue.

Comment: @Ashan yes, You are right. When I attached "AmazonDynamoDBFullAccess" policy, it started working. Please add your comment as an answer, I will accept it. But that is not helping me from wondering, how am I able to scan the entire table and do PUT operations without that policy.

Comment: I just updated the answer for future references for others.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This seems like a permission issue.

Double check the IAM policy inside the IAM Role attached to the Lambda function, whether it has AmazonDynamoDBFullAccess or Custom Policy including 'query' action granted.

```
  "Effect": "Allow",
  "Action" [
        dynamodb:Query
   ]
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, but the accepted solution alone did not work for me.  I got everything to work fine if I did not provide a table arn in the permissions, but just made it work for all tables.  Sure, it works, but that's hardly a secure solution.

I found that I had to specify the arn for the GSI I was querying on in the IAM permissions.  So instead of specifying the arn for the table, I specified the arn for the specific index I wanted to query on.  And then it worked.  Maybe there's a more elegant solution, but this is what worked for me.